# creating pre to post labels from visit day/time

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, new-operator

I have this data set in where participants were given a visit day. So in order to differentiate when pre testing happens and post testing happens I need to first match them to their participant id.

I would like to mutate the lower value from visit time to "pre" and the higher value to "post"? any ideas how I can achieve this? Thank you very much!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qimXB.png)

Comment: Please create your data.frame as a reproducible object like `df <- data.frame(ID = ....` or use `dput(df)` on your data if it already exists. Pasting data or text as images is generally discouraged here.

Comment: You might want to read [ask] and [MCVE] as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want something like this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(pre = min(Visit),
         post = max(Visit)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```